# Concatenation of two columns from the same file

Tags: bash, shell, awk

From a text file

> file
>
> ```
> a    d
> b    e
> c    f
> ```

how are the tab delimited columns concatenated into one column

> ```
> a
> b
> c
> d
> e
> f
> ```

Now I use *awk* to output columns to two files that I then concatenated using *cat*. But there must be a better one line command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a generalized approach

```
$ f() { awk '{print $'$1'}' file; }; f 1; f 2

a
b
c
d
e
f
```

if the file is tab delimited perhaps simply with `cut` (the inverse operation of `paste`)

```
$ cut -f1 file.t; cut -f2 file.t
```

Comment: The cut method seems to be the fastest way to concatenate the files. I will run this on a text file with 64 millions of rows so speed is welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

This simple awk command should do the job:

```
awk '{print $1; s=s $2 ORS} END{printf "%s", s}' file
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: IMHO, I think OP's requested output is different than above as OP needs to have first $1 print and then $2.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh13, I overlooked that part. It is corrected now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use process substitution; that would eliminate the need to create file for each column.

```
$ cat file 
a    d
b    e
c    f
$ cat <(awk '{print $1}' file) <(awk '{print $2}' file)
a
b
c
d
e
f
$
```

OR

as per the comment you can just combine multiple commands and redirect their output to a different file like this:

```
$ cat file 
a    d
b    e
c    f
$ (awk '{print $1}' file; awk '{print $2}' file) > output
$ cat output 
a
b
c
d
e
f
$
```

Comment: In this case, `cat` looks useless: `(awk '{print $1}' file; awk '{print $2}' file)` should be enough.

Comment: the subshell is not needed either, just `awk ..; awk ..` will do.

Answer (score 0):

try: Without reading file twice or without any external calls of any other commands, only single awk to rescue. Also considering that your Input_file is same like shown sample.

```
awk '{VAL1=VAL1?VAL1 ORS $1:$1;VAL2=VAL2?VAL2 ORS $2:$2} END{print VAL1 ORS VAL2}'   Input_file
```

**Explanation:** Simply creating a variable named VAL1 which will contain $1's value and keep on concatenating in it's own value, VAL2 will have $2's value and keep on concatenating value in it's own. In END section of awk printing the values of VAL1 and VAL2.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine bash commands with `;` to get a single stream:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' file; awk '{print $2}' file
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Use process substitution if you want that to be as if it were a single file:

```
$ txt=$(awk '{print $1}' file; awk '{print $2}' file)
$ echo "$txt"
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Or for a Bash `while` loop:

```
$ while read -r line; do echo "line: $line"; done < <(awk '{print $1}' file; awk '{print $2}' file)
line: a
line: b
line: c
line: d
line: e
line: f
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using notepadd++ you could replace all tab values with the newl[image]ine char "\r\n"

Comment: He is asking about using bash scripts (see the tags).

Comment: Also, this would interleave the columns.

Answer (score -1):

another approach:

```
for i in $(seq 1 2); do
    awk '{print $'$i'}' file
done
```

output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

Comment: This only works if the input happens to be sorted, but not in the general case.

Comment: It interleaves and then sorts. Assume the input looks like `a b\nc d`. Desired output is `a\nc\nb\nd`, but your output would be `a\nb\nc\nd`.

Comment: The delimiter is inserted between $1 and $2, LF(\n) is not a literal value depending on how you insert it. This is indeed a\nd<LF>b\ne<LF>c\nf

Comment: Very fast compared to the other methods. Probably as it only reads every line only once. But as mentioned it does not concatenate the columns. But it can perhaps be very useful.

Comment: please restore answer to 0, eventhough you preferred other method over this

Comment: I didn't vote, by the way, but it is still wrong. The input file is tab delimited. Consider `echo $'a\tb\nc\td'`: this prints a line `a b` (tab delimited), then `c d`. I hope you agree that the correct output for this should be four lines, in the order `a c b d`. Now, running your solution, `awk '{OFS="\n"};{print $1,$2}' <<< $'a\tb\nc\td'` results in four lines `a b c d` even before sorting, and stays obviously the same after sorting. How is this correct?