# Concatenation of columns from the same stream

Tags: bash, shell, cut

Related to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44165958/concatenation-of-two-columns-from-the-same-file).

From a stream with columns.

> cat file
>
> ```
> a    d    1    4
> b    e    2    5
> c    f    3    6
> ```

How are the columns/fields concatenated into columns, e.g. like this.

> ```
> a    1
> b    2
> c    3
> d    4
> e    5
> f    6
> ```

I have tried to use my preferred command `cut` as shown below, but with only the output from the first `cut` command.

> `cat file | ( cut -f1,3; cut -f2,4; )`
>   or
>   `cat file | { cut -f1,3; cut -f2,4; }`
>
> ```
> a    1
> b    2
> c    3
> ```

Comment: `awk '{print $1,$3}' file; awk '{print $2,$4}' file`

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you could do

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF-2;i++)a[$i]=$(i+2)}END{for(i in a)print i,a[i]}' test

a 1
b 2
c 3
d 4
e 5
f 6
```

So save keys into an associative array and assign the field after next to it.

Note this will not preserve order though, it is just coincidence if it does.

Also your original

```
cat file | ( cut -f1,3; cut -f2,4; )
```

Does not work because the first cut consumes the stream and it never gets to the second.

You could do something like

```
<file tee >(cut -f2,4) >(cut -f1,3) >/dev/null
```

Which would send the stream to both commands.

Answer (score 0):

`cat file |` = useless use of cat ; one can use `< file` instead

```
cut -f1,3 <file
cut -f2,4 <file
```

but from performance point of view, it launches 2 processes, opens file twice and reads twice, this can be done with builtins

```
str=
while read k1 k2 v1 v2; do
    echo "$k1"$'\t'"$v1"
    str=$str$k2$'\t'$v2$'\n'
done < file
echo -n "$str"
```

EDIT: because of poor performance of read, for big files it would be better to use a text processing tool like awk, sed or more complete perl, here a one-liner for example:

```
perl -a -pe '$_="$F[0]\t$F[2]\n";$s.="$F[1]\t$F[3]\n";END{print$s}' <file
```

Comment: A `while`/`read` loop is slow, and whatever you gain by not starting a dedicated process is lost unless you have a *very* small file.

Comment: I agree, but it depends on what's done in loop here I use only simple variable expansion and echo builtin if a process expansion or sub-shell is called it will be worst

Comment: The reading *alone* is slower. You can have an empty loop body and it will be slower than `cat`.

Comment: that's true `perl -e 'print "hello\n"x1000000' | { while read; do :; done;}` / `perl -e 'print "hello\n"x1000000' | cat > /dev/null`